# Reduction of 2-cyclohexenone to cyclohexanol

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, reference-request, organic-reduction

Is $\ce{NaBH4}$ a suitable reducing agent for the conversion of 2-cyclohexenone to cyclohexanol?

In Clayden (page 506, second edition), I have found the reduction of cyclopentenone to cyclopentanol using $\ce{NaBH4}$ in $\ce{Et-OH}$. (99% yield!). First NaBH4 performs 1,4 addition and then 1,2 addition to give the product.

However, I am unable to find a reference for reduction of cyclohexenone to cyclohexanol.

I found this in [Smith](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=QY5pKDTTK4YC&pg=PA730&lpg=PA730&dq=Cyclohexenone%20with%20NaBH4&source=bl&ots=MQBq4W0C0w&sig=C2tK_LXub67hWB9nfGNdWQxs-eI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDr4S1t5_cAhWJQ48KHRk7Bgw4ChDoAQhKMAY#v=onepage&q&f=false):
[image]

I don't understand why it can't reduce the double bond through Michael addition in case of cyclohex-2-enone as well. What is the reason behind it?

Comment: Whether NaBH4 reduces the C=C double bond seems to be substrate dependent (and more often than not, it actually doesn't reduce it). And I am not sure if there is any pattern to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Johnson, M. R.; Rickborn B. Sodium borohydride reduction of conjugated aldehydes and ketones *J. Org. Chem.,* **1970,** *35,* 1041.
[DOI: 10.1021/jo00829a039](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo00829a039):

2-Cyclohexenone can certainly be reduced fully. It has very similar reactivity to cyclopentenone. In this report, mixtures of products were observed. The experimental indicates the researchers used 0.5 eq of $\ce{NaBH4}$ per carbonyl.

[image]

Furthermore, the use of Luche conditions can again help you favor only 1,2 reduction:

[image]

Comment: I am just curious. Could you elaborate on the principle of Luche reduction? What effect does the cerium (III) ion have on the conjugated enone?

Comment: @TanYongBoon this site has a good explanation: https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/luche-reduction.shtm